# How to pass two arguments id and slug with url (routing) in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5, slug

It's very simple But I don't know how? I want to show post id and slug in URL like "http://localhost:8000/blog/27/this-is-test-post" but it's not working

**My route**

```
Route::get('blog/{id}/{slug}',['as'=>'blog.single','uses'=>'PageController@getSingle']);
```

**My Controller**

```
public function getSingle($id)
{
 $article=Article::where('id','=','$id')->first();
 return view('/articles/article')->withArticle($article);
}
```

"i want to fetch data by id so i use here only id"

**My View**

when i Use this, URL is Perfect but it's show Error "Trying to get property of non-object"

```
<a href="blog/{{$article->id}}/{{$article->slug}}" > {{$article->title}}</a></h3>
```

when I use this

```
<a href="blog/{{$article->id}}{{$article->slug}}" > {{$article->title}}</a></h3>
```

then my URL like http://localhost:8000/blog/27this-is-test-post (without any Error)

[image]

Comment: Change `Article::where('id','=','$id')->first();` to `Article::where('id','=',$id)->first();`

Comment: oohhh , great it's work great.... thanksss your are genius

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`route`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-route) helper.

```
route('blog.single', ['id' => $article->id, 'slug' => $article->slug]);
```

In your link:

```
<a href="{{ route('blog.single', ['id' => $article->id, 'slug' => $article->slug]) }}">{{ $article->title }}</a>
```

Comment: It's Sounds Good but Please more Explain about Route Helper

Comment: @brij: Read the link.

Answer (score 2):

You can use route helper

`route('blog.single', ['id' => $article->id, 'slug' => $article->slug]);`

Or define 2 parameters in controller method i.e

```
public function getSingle($id,$slug)
 {
  $article=Article::where('id','=','$id')->first();
  return view('/articles/article')->withArticle($article);
 }
```

because you have defined 2 parameters in route. Try it will work fine.
You have to use route helper for generating url for form action or link href where you want to place it for click or post i.e

```
<a href='{{ route('folders.list') }}'>Folders</a>
```

or

```
{{ route('folders.list',['id' => 1]) }}
```

or you can also make your link as

```
<a href={{URL::to('blog/'.$article->id.'/'.$article->slug)}}>Some Link</a>
```

it will also work fine

Comment: Thanks , Khan i am new in laravel please tell me where i use route helper

Comment: You have to use route helper for generating url for form action or link href where you want to place it for click or post i.e <a href='{{  route('folders.list') }}'>Folders</a> or {{ route('folders.list',['id' => 1]) }}

Comment: in link place it <a href={{URL::to('blog/'.$article->id.'/'.$article->slug)}}>Some Link</a> it should work fine

Comment: yes it's right can you share screen shot after inspecting your created link with browser inspect tool? then I can guide you in better way

Comment: but your error shows that your object is missing some value can you send me line no. 8 from view article.blage