# Product slug and id in implicit routing

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to figure out how to use/display the slug of my product and the id in my product URL, using implicit binding with Laravel.

Using `getRouteKeyName()` which returns the product `slug` I'm able to display the slug of my product e.g. `store.com/product/my-awesome-product`. I also want to add the ID of the product at the end of the URL e.g. `store.com/product/my-awesome-product/1`.

Is this possible with `getRouteKeyName()` or do I have to preform a query finding the product by the ID and slug, like in this post: [How to pass two arguments id and slug with url (routing) in laravel 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48815749/how-to-pass-two-arguments-id-and-slug-with-url-routing-in-laravel-5-1).

Or is it also possible to ignore the product slug, but still have it in the url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a parameter in the url which is just for the seo(representational) purpose and does not contribute to the logic inside controller.

so :

```
Route::get('products/{productID}/{ProductName}', 'ProducController@show')->name('product.show');
```

and inside controller :

```
public function show($productId, $productName){

  $product = Product::findOrFail($id);

  // You can add this optional check to 
  // make sure product name is correct
  $slug = str_slug($product->name, '-');

  if(!str_contains($slug, $productName)){
    abort(404);
  }

  return view('product')->with(compact('product'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a closed issue present in laravel github issues however you can try something like this:

```
Route::get('products/{product:slug}', 'ProducController@show')->name('product.show'); // Finds product by slug.
Route::get('products/{product}', 'ProducController@show')->name('product.show'); // Finds Product by ID (or whatever is defined in getRouteKeyName()).

route('product.show', $product) -> store.com/product/my-awesome-product
route('product.show', $product) -> store.com/product/1
```

For more details check this [link](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/18197)